# expose gps NMEA stream through the Android OS

Tags: android, android-ndk, gpsd

I am trying to run a C application/driver on Android that reads the serial NMEA stream coming from the GPS device.  I can run this driver on a Linux platform with success as long as I am reading from the correct device (Ex. /dev/ttyUSB0, ttyS0, etc.).

The driver runs on the Android OS, but I don't know how the device is exposed to the Operating System, so I can't read in the GPS stream.  Does anyone know if this can be accessed directly via the OS or if I need an additional driver/kernel mod?

I am not looking for any LocationManager or JNI answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it has to be LocationManager API unless you have a rooted handset.
The long route is to get the GPS stream by implementing a GpsStatus.NmeaListener and call a JNI callback and get the stream in C. But I didn't think that was what you are after. I think you want to have direct access to serial device which has GPS hardware connected. This I think is difficult to achieve with the android security/permissions model.